# does synchronisation on hashtable applies for whole class

Tags: java

I have a basic doubt in java.

Assume there is a Class A with a synchronised method M in it. If i create an object A1 for Class A and access that synchronised method M, then the object A1 is locked by the synchronised method M.

I am creating a method with return type of Hashtable(which is internally a synchronised one) Does it act in the similar way like above method? Will the entire object become inaccessible till it is executing the method with return type of Hashtable?

Comment: No only the accessors and mutator methods are synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

No, the entire object will not be inaccessible.

But what will happen is that *all* other methods marked `synchronized` will block until your method that returns the Hashtable completes (either by returning a value, throwing an Exception, etc).

In other words, if both method M and N are syncrhonized, considering the same object instance then one can't process until the other completes. And method A that is not sychronized can be executed at any time :)

By the way if you need more complex syncrhonization, you can synchronize on any `Object`... but usually the keyword before method names is sufficient.